# Does anyone know what the different between binary mesh from CaptureReality &binary mesh from blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, assimp

I use the Capture Reality export 3d mesh with binary and try to use assimp to open it, but it's not going to work, but after import this mesh into blender, without any manual changes, export directly, try open with the Assimp, then it work?

Is anyone know what the different inside?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy: these are different model formats.

- At this moment the blender format, which is supported by the Asset-Importer-Lib from versions less than 2.90.
- The Capture Reality export 3d mesh is a different file format, which is not supported at this moment.

Comment: Got it, thanks. 
I also met another problems, with the ASCII FBX export from Capture Reality, sometimes fbx 2020  also can't  open by the Assimp library, but it works with the previous like FBX 2019,FBX2018 etc, by the way i think i still using Assimp 4.1.0